# Using jQuery or JavaScript to wrap a <span> with an <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="productAttributeRow productAttributeConfigurablePickListSet" id="6921e34863c90e71a28b72aaa26e1af4">
<div class="productAttributeLabel">
    <label for="c63471e76af04e3ff10e3b568d54e012">
        <span class="name">Add Matching Panties (6905):</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="productAttributeValue">

<div class="productOptionViewRectangle">
<ul class="list-horizontal">
                    <li class="
    option
        ">
    <label for="e0eebcbec82d5048b186e5683668a888">
        <input type="radio" class="validation" name="attribute[1361]" value="1044" id="e0eebcbec82d5048b186e5683668a888">
        <span class="name">XS</span>
    </label>
</li>

                    <li class="
    option
        ">
    <label for="7d7b61c404930891d9d027ef9da67a14">
        <input type="radio" class="validation" name="attribute[1361]" value="1045" id="7d7b61c404930891d9d027ef9da67a14">
        <span class="name">S</span>
    </label>
</li>


    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is put an a tag around the span tag inside the first label tag with JS after the page loads. I am using a CMS that doesn't allow changing this kind of stuff directly but it can be changed with JS once the page loads.
I am not really sure where to even start with this one, I am still not very experienced with JS. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: jQuery has a [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function which will probably solve your dilemma. As @DSG put it, please make an attempt

Comment: `$('label .name:first').wrap('<a />')`

Answer (score 1):

If using jQuery:

```
$('.productAttributeLabel span').wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
```

Comment: You were correct. I did not notice he wanted only the first one.

Comment: You should probably use single quotes.

Comment: Updated, good call @CharlieM.

Comment: Quick side question, why would you use .each() in this case? Wouldn't a straight selector just be better?

Comment: Yep, you're right. On a second look, the `.each()` was unnecessary - I updated to reference the selector more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery's wrap method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$('span.name:first').wrap('<a href="your path"></a>');
```

Comment: I think `span.name` would get the other spans too, OP's looking for the first.

Answer (score 0):

just like `yourspan.wrap('<a href="#"></a>');`

```
$('span').wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".productAttributeRow").find("label:first span").wrap("<a href='somelink'></a>");
```